# Replacing adjectives from one book into another using textblob

Tags: python, string, text, replace, textblob

I am trying to create a program that will replace the adjectives from one text file, which I am using Pride and Prejudice (pride.txt) and replace them with the adjectives from another text file, which I am using Moby Dick (moby.txt). I am very new to textblob and would appreciate any guidance on how to start.

Answer (score 0):

**A beginner solution:**
open pride.txt read it into a string then split it by space to a list.(same for moby.txt).
loop ur pride list when u find an adjective loop ur moby list to find the replacment then attribute it to the pride list. when loop is done join ur list into one string and overwrite ur pride.txt

Note: flagged down questions doesn't bring any viewers. structure ur question and present more info.  hope this can help u.